# What unicellular eukaryotes reproduce sexually?

Tags: cell-biology, sexual-reproduction

By sexual reproduction I am referring to, at least, gametogenesis or mating bridges. I was previously under the impression that unicellular organisms did not reproduce sexually at all.

So far the sexually reproducing unicellular eukaryotes I am aware of are yeast, diatoms, malaria-causing *Plasmodium* and [some diplomonads](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/56573/23982).

Comment: Your definition of simplest is not exactly exclusive.

Comment: Huh! According to this article it is possible that sexual reproduction is the standard in eukaryotes: https://ittakes30.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/rewriting-the-history-of-sex/

Answer (score 1):

This addresses your original question of "simplest" versus smallest. I'm not sure of sizes.

Investigate diplomonads: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomonad Most notable among them is Giardia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giardia

These critters are primitive enough to lack Golgi and their version of "mitochondria" are substantially different enough (not synthesizing ATP) to be called by another name, mitosomes. Most have two nucleii and were not even thought to reproduce sexually  until relatively recently